# Fire Chosen plugin after creating Select box via Xajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, jquery-chosen

I want to bind the Jquery plugin `Chosen` on a select box that I create via Xajax, the Select does not figure in the DOM when the page is loaded.

So I start by returning the select box and then I execute `.chosen()` on the box ID:

```
<? $objResponse = new xajaxResponse();
$objResponse->assign($selectID, 'innerHTML', $codeThatCreatesSelectBox);
$objResponse->script('$(function(){ $("#selectID").chosen(); });');
return $objResponse; ?>
```

But I'm obviously doing something wrong...
How could I do this ?

EDIT

I tried waiting for ajax returns before firing the plugin by using ajaxComplete() :

```
$objResponse->script('$("#selectID").ajaxComplete(function() {$("#selectID").chosen(); });');
```

But it doesn't change anything..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a callback to do this.
From the documentation: http://www.xajax-project.org/En/docs-tutorials/upgrading-from-xajax-0-2-x-to-0-5/

```
myCallback = xajax.callback.create(100, 10000);
myCallback.onRequest = function()
{
    xajax. $('loadingMsg').style.display = 'block';
};
myCallback.onComplete = function()
{
    xajax. $('loadingMsg').style.display = 'none';
};

// then, on the PHP side, specify the callback option when registering your function:
$xajax->register(XAJAX_FUNCTION, 'myFunction', array(
    'callback' => 'myCallback'
));
```

So you can call your jQuery plugin code inside the desired callback.